# Computer Super slow after syncing with one drive (windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive

My computer is very slow after I synced my onedrive in my computer. The C drive is not loading and deleting a trivial file is taking forever. Here is a screenshot

[windows_10_stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foizT.jpg)

I already tried restarting my computer, running chkdsk from powershell (admin). Cleaning junk files. Nothing is fixing this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to disable OneDrive sync?

Comment: Syncing sends info over the internet. If the connection is slow, the PC wiil be slow.

Comment: I agree with @harrymc - try disabling OneDrive first and see what happens.  Is the drive an SSD or HDD?  Look in eventvwr to see if there are any disk errors or anything else that sticks out.  You could also try using something like Hirens or a Windows install ISO/USB to delete the file offline.  If eventvwr doesn't show any disk errors, yet it still takes forever to delete the file(s) offline, I would probably start running some tests on the drive.  Process Monitor and Process Explorer might provide some insight into the IO operations happening on your system.

Comment: My drive is an HDD. I actually need to use Onedrive because all my university files are synced with my university computer and home computer. I am looking for an answer how can I fix the issues with my computer without uninstalling or disabling onedrive.

Comment: Has onedrive actually finished synchronising?

Comment: yes it finished. But still the computer is very slow.

Comment: Make sure you have a local copy of your data. It appears no and then your computer is getting all documents from the OneDrive server and slow doing that.

Comment: Everytime you access a file, OneDrive will manage it which slows things down. I have the same problem. I tried to store my documents to OneDrive, and now starting Powershell is really slow and onedrive syncs. Once done, Powershell can be used.

Comment: *My drive is an HDD*... Any OS running in an old HDD will be really slow, no matter what you do or don't do. This is something you must make peace with or replace it with solid state media, period. File sync and low free space are situations that make it much worse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and run elevated CMD a "chkdsk /f" and reboot. Solves most issues with OneDrive and it's sync.

Comment: This _really_ needs an explanation of exactly what it does, and why it would solve the issue.

Comment: "chkdsk" ran on Windows(any) needs an explanation?
We can try that with also CMD(doesnt have to be elevated);
chkdsk /?
Checks a disk and displays a status report.

Comment: Yes. Why would _checking the disk_ have anything to do with OneDrive?

Comment: This statement actually comes from wide spread issue that I have(with clients), where multiple users are using single file or shared folder. Sometimes for "one" user it simply wont sync properly(or at all), by accident I found out that most of my users sync issues are solved with "chkdsk /f",...as of what chkdsk does during scan, I wont even care to dwell into it.